# rspec steak acceptance test with i18n html keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How I could test I18n html keys with the rspec steak gem?

```
feature 'about page - not signed in user' do

   background do
     visit '/about'
   end

  scenario 'visit about page' do
   page.should have_content(I18n.t("pages.about.headline_html"))
   page.should have_content(I18n.t("pages.about.body_html"))
  end

end
```

I always get following:

```
..FF

Failures:

 1) about page - not signed in user visit about page
 Failure/Error: page.should have_content(I18n.t("pages.about.headline_html"))
   expected there to be content "<h1>About</h1>" in "About"
```

Anybody an idea?

I already tried:

```
page.should have_content(I18n.t("pages.about.headline_html").html_safe)
```

EDIT: If I include

```
include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper
```

into my feature and I do like that:

```
headline = strip_tags(I18n.t("pages.about.headline_html"))
body = strip_tags(I18n.t("pages.about.body_html"))
page.should have_content(headline)
page.should have_content(body)
```

everything works.

What do you think about this solution? Seems to be a bit hacky I think..

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work for you:
    page.html.should include(I18n.t("pages.about.headline_html"))

similar question is here: [Capybara: should have html content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981820/capybara-should-have-html-content)