# Capybara: should have html content

Tags: rspec, capybara

How I can check html content on the page with capybara?

```
page.should have_text('this is <b>bold</b> "text"')
```

output:

```
Failure/Error: page.should have_text('this is <b>bold</b> "text"')
  expected there to be this is <b>bold</b> \"text\" in "....this is bold \"text\"....."
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the HTML in an element using Capybara?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071937/how-do-i-get-the-html-in-an-element-using-capybara)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your code doesn't work as Capybara's `has_text?` (and thus `have_text`) method checks text, not html source of the element it is invoked on.

If you use driver that supports Javascript evaluation (e.g. Selenium, Poltergeist or Capybara-Webkit) you can get inner HTML of the element using Javascript:

```
html = page.evaluate_script("document.getElementById('answer-15988092').innerHTML")
html.should include('this is <b>bold</b> "text"')
```

If you want to assert that the entire HTML of the page contains an element you can use `html` method that returns page source:

```
page.html.should include('this is <b>bold</b> "text"')
```

Usually I prefer javascript evaluation as it's more restrictive.

Comment: I have tried a number of valid elements up to and including `id`, `div#id`, and `body`. In each case, I get this rejection `unknown error: Cannot read property innerHTML of null`